# Fast Python Array Function to Complete calculation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Trying to calc number of Palindromes (numbers that are the same forwards and backwards) but obviously crashing my PC and it takes VERY long.

What is the correct way to run this as an array function, instead of a for loop, so it is optimised for speed ?

Pls help thx!

```
begin = 0
end = 2500000000000000

palindromes = 0

for i in range(begin, end+1, 1):
    if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:  
       palindromes += 1
     
print( palindromes)
```

Comment: Array-based solutions are not practical, as most computers cannot allocate for nearly 18 PiB of memory.

Comment: You should rethink your algorithm. Testing every number is not practical, as you've found out. Perhaps you can use an algorithm to *construct* every possible palindrome number between `begin` and `end` (in fact, if you find such an algorithm, you might be able to compute the number of palindromes directly, using basic math, instead of computing it).

Comment: How to you come to this conclusion 18PiB ? 
If that is the case you may be right, could there be a way to dump memory by batching...there must be a way to compute number of palindromes between 0-2.5E-15.
Any helpful insights would be very much appreciated.

Comment: An array of 2500000000000000 numbers will take up about 2500000000000000 / 10^15 P(i)B, *times* the amount of bytes required to store a single number (8 bytes in Python); which is about 18 PiB.

Comment: To take the typo in your comment literally: in the range 0-2.5E-15, there is 1 palindrome number: 0. You probably meant between 0 and 2.5E15.

Comment: You are attempting 2500,000Billion loops each of which takes a lot of processor cycles, especially in Python. It's not going to be realistic; nor is there any 'array function' which can help - how could it. You need a smarter way to construct palindromes. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344284) and specifically the `Quant Metropolis` answer which might help.

Comment: The  `Quant Metropolis`  approach mentioned above gives the answer 124999999 in a few minutes. But you don't need to do the calculation - if you do: 250, 2500, 25000, 250000 you will see the pattern emerging and can just write down the answer.

Comment: `numpy` does not have a way of wrapping a block of python code and making it "fast and memory efficient".  It isn't that kind of module.  For efficiency in numpy you have to make numpy arrays (numeric ones), and use the existing, compiled numpy methods.  And you have to learn some basic numpy first.